# How to adjust date_select / time_select field size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been attempting to adjust the size of my form fields. I have tried using size like so...

```
<%= f.date_select(:form_date, order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { month: 'Select Month', day: 'Select Day', year: 'Select Year' }, start_year: 2000, size: 1) %>
```

Am I just entering size in the wrong order (size: 1 shouldn't be last)? Is this best handled in my stylesheets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was mixing options and html_options

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {}) Link
```

Here is what I changed my line of code to from above...

```
<%= f.date_select(:form_date, options = { order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { month: 'Select Month', day: 'Select Day', year: 'Select Year' }, start_year: 2000 }, html_options = { size: 1 }) %>
```